# View in browser link - search results

Tags: 2010

Why is the 'View in browser'link appearing In my search results? OWA is installed in the farm but isn't associated with the web application in question. The office web apps feature is deactivated at site collection level and the 'open in client app' feature is activated. Link is appearing for Word, Excel and PowerPoint documents.

When a user clicks on this link to open a document, it screen sits for a while and then displays an error saying it could open the file.  If I associate the equivalent service app in configure service associations it works but I don't want to. Can I just get rid of the link or why is it rendering?

Answer (score 1):

When installing Office Web Applications it changes the Visualization of the Federated Location to include this link.

You can either change the default:

- go into Central Admin | Manage Service Applications | Search Service Application | Federated Location
- click Local Search Results
- Expand Display Information
- In Core Search Results Display Metadata
- Edit the XSL
- Remove the following section:

  ```
  <xsl:call-template name="ViewInBrowser">
    <xsl:with-param name="browserlink" select="serverredirectedurl" />
    <xsl:with-param name="currentId" select="$currentId" />
  </xsl:call-template>
  ```
- Go into the search result page of the search center of web application where you want the link to display
- Put page in edit mode
- Select Edit Web Part on Search Core Results
- Expand Display Properties
- Deselect Use Location Visualization
- Click XLS Editor to edit the XSLT and put the section back below this section:

  ```
  <xsl:call-template name="DisplayCollapsingStatusLink">
    <xsl:with-param name="status" select="collapsingstatus"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="workid" select="workid"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="id" select="concat($currentId,'_CS')"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
  ```

Or can use the last steps described above to remove it from Search Centers of web applications where you don't want it